# Javascript scrollIntoView function not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that use a HTML select element. It works by each option having number value. When the option is click I use that number to scroll to a div.

Something like this:

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

function test() {
  var t = parseInt(this.value);
  divs[t].scrollIntoView({
    block: "center",
    behaviour: "smooth"
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].addEventListener("click", test);
  }
});
```

```css
div{
height:50vh;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Div 1</option>
  <option value="1">Div 2</option>
  <option value="2">Div 3</option>
  <option value="3">Div 4</option>
</select>
<div>
<hr>
div 1
</div>
<div>
<hr>
div 2
</div>
<div>
<hr>
div 3
</div>
<div>
<hr>
div 4
</div>
```

This works in Firefox and IE but not in chrome. The options have the function attached but when I click them nothing happens.

Comment: What does the F12 developer console tell you about errors and warnings?

Comment: Please define "_not working_".

Comment: @Teemu not scrolling into view.
 I'm on Linux and Chrome not Scroling; Firefox scrolling but ignores `smooth` behavior.

Comment: But that is not supported in IE either.

Comment: It looks like the click event is not fired by option elements in Chrome. I'm surprised this actually works in IE ... Maybe listening `onchange` on the select element would do in Chrome too ..?

Comment: there is a typo in your "addEventListenr", it is missing letter e at the end, it probably is not going to fix your issue but at least people save time correcting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have the example code here: https://codepen.io/danieldd/pen/ZVzvYB

Its working fine in chrome, maybe if you can share the logs or your chrome version.

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Div 1</option>
  <option value="2">Div 2</option>
  <option value="3">Div 3</option>
  <option value="4">Div 4</option>
</select>

<div id="container_1">div 1</div>
<div id="container_2">div 2</div>
<div id="container_3">div 3</div>
<div id="container_4">div 4</div>
```

```js
var dropdownElement = document.getElementById('dropdown');

dropdownElement.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    var containerChoosed = document.getElementById('container_' + this.value);
    containerChoosed.scrollIntoView({ block: "center", behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks, not sure why "click" worked on firefox and IE but not chrome. Is the smooth scroll working for you?

Comment: Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) - I am not able to see the smooth behaviour.

Comment: Not working in my Chrome - Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official build)

Comment: @Daniel, misspelled `behavior` as `behaviour`. codepen wont work unless spelling has been corrected. (: might wanna make a small edit

Comment: **behavior** wording fixed :)

Comment: The smooth scroll doesn't work. It just jumps to the anchor..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call `scrollIntoView()` onwheel, you have to cancel the default action (if you don't cancel the default action, you can't `scrollIntoView()` because the browser is already scrolling a little bit, so the `scrollIntoView` function doesn't do anything).
To cancel the default action, you have to use `e.preventDefault()` in the callback function. However, the `wheel` event is by default not cancellable. To make the event cancellable, you  can set the `passive` attribute to false on options.
Here's a working solution :

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', wheelListener, {passive: false}); 
function wheelListener(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mySecondDiv.scrollIntoView(); // works !
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem in Chrome. This helped, put at the end of the page and into a separate script element:

```js
<script>
    window.setTimeout( ()=>{ window.scrollTo(0,0) }, 50 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the scrolling failure in a different situation: call scrollIntoView with smooth behavior and after that, set the focus to the parent element for further keyboard scroll.
The solution was to focus the parent element before calling scrollIntoView.